# Sort odd and even numbers separatedly and move all odd numbers in front

Tags: algorithm

For example, if the input array is
  832461905
The output is
  1357902468

I think this can be done in two steps 
1) sort data
  012345678
2) move odd numbers in front of even numbers by preserving order
  To do so, we can have two pointers
  Initially one points to the beginning and the other points to the end
   Move the head util even numbers are found
   The move the tail until odd numbers are found
   Swap data at the pointers
   Do the above until the two pointers meet

My question is if we can solve the problem by using one step rather than two

Comment: Absolutely you can do it in one step, just use a comparison that puts all odd numbers less than even ones.

Comment: How long *(length)* your number could be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a little comp-function for sorting:

```cpp
bool comp(int x, int y)
{
    if (x % 2 == y % 2) return x < y;
    return x % 2 > y % 2;
}
...
sort(your_array.begin(), your_array.end(), comp);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done in one step.

Write your own comparison function, and use `std::sort` in C++:

```cpp
sort(data.begin(),data.end(),comp);

bool comp(int x,int y)
{
    if (x%2==0)     
    {
        if(y%2==0)
        {
            return x<y;   // if both are even
        }
        else
        {
            return false;    // if only x is even
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(y%2==0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return x<y;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am considering you are familiar with **C++**. See my **code** snippet, and `yes` it can be done in a step:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

bool function(int a, int b) {
    if(a%2 != b%2) {                /* When one is even and another is odd */   
        if(a&1) {                   
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {                        /* When both are either odd or even */
        return (a<b);
    }
}

int main() {
    int input[10005];                 /* Input array */
    int n = -1, i;

    /* Take the input */
    while(scanf("%i", &input[++n]) != EOF);

    /* Sort according to desire condition */
    std::sort(input, input+n, function);

    /* Time to print out the values */
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        std::cout << input[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Any confusion, comments most welcome.

Comment: I think your solution works for only digits for 0 to 9. The question is about any integers.

Comment: @JoeC. I understood it wrong that's why it did it in that way. OK. let me  fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Under the `<algorithm>` library in C++ you can use `sort` to order the numbers and then `stable_partition` to separate by odd and even.

Like so:

```cpp
auto arr = std::valarray<int>{8,3,2,4,6,1,9,0,5};
std::sort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
std::stable_partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int a){ return a % 2; });
```

Resulting in a rather succinct solution.